# KML Regions feature not working in Google Earth 8.0.2.2334 installed on Android

Tags: kml, google-earth, android

When I load a kml in Google Earth 8.0.2.2334 installed on my Android phone, the KML Regions feature is not working (for me).
I have read and reread the Google Dev pages. I have googled for a solution for two days.

I am really hoping somebody will simply alter one of the examples below and then I will load it to my phone and see that it is possible to set *limitations* (zoom dependent) to when my data (kml) is visible in Google Earth on my phone. or load an example of their own.

I want to keep this simple so I will use existing samples to show how the feature  works as intended on my and most likely your PC version of Google Earth but then not at all on my phone's Google Earth app.

Sample Examples can be found at Google's KML Samples webpage, just scroll down that page to find the "Region KML" examples

Here are two of them:

http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Region/polygon-simple.kml

http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/Region/polygon-swap-pop.kml

As you might have read on Google Developers website:

"Regions are a powerful KML feature that allows you to add very large datasets to Google Earth without sacrificing performance. Data is loaded and drawn only when it falls within the user's view and occupies a certain portion of the screen. Using Regions, you can supply separate levels of detail for the data, so that fine details are loaded only when the data fills a portion of the screen that is large enough for the details to be visible."

I want to know how to make them work on my phone please.
In case you ask:
Android ver. 5.0.1
HTC Sence ver 6.0
Google Earth 8.0.2.2334